# An uncountable subset in $\Bbb{R}^n$ in which each $n$ elemented subset is a base

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Using Zorn's Lemma I can show that there is an uncountable subset in $\Bbb{R}^n$ such that any $n$-elemented subset is independent. Can you construct such a set ??

Answer (score 10):

$$\{\,(1,t,\ldots,t^{n-1})\mid t\in\mathbb R\,\}$$

Comment: Vandermonde Vor the Vin.

Comment: @dimo: Based on Hagen's answer, it is easy to give $n!$ different sets :-)

Comment: coffeemath, $n$ is the dimension of the space as well as the size of subset considered. If you would like an uncountable set in $\mathbb{R}$ such that every 1-element subset is independent, I can provide you with many. :)

Comment: @Andrew My oversight! they most agree for independence to work, should have seen that.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Hagen's answer, this one also works for $n=1$:
$$\left\{(t,t^2,\ldots,t^n)\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\right\}$$

Answer (score 1):

On repeated request by user dimo, here is a generalization. Again, kudos to Hagen without whose answer this would not have been given by me.

Generalization: Let $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ be polynomials from $\mathbb{R}[X]$ where $\deg p_i = i$ and $p_i(0)=0$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Then
$$\left\{\left(p_1(t),p_2(t),\ldots,p_n(t)\right)\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\right\}$$
has the requested property, as we can reduce the determinants in question to a Vandermonde determinant with nonzero multipliers, and the restrictions given exclude the zero tuple.

Edit: All $p_i$ must have $p_i(0)=0$, not just $p_1$, otherwise the reduction does not work completely.